# How to use ORDER BY with UNION in SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I have two tables ..
I need to select some records till total sum values to be >= threshold but I am using 2 select statements with different where statements with using UNION.

I select from table1 and join table2 but i need order results in every select statements separately depending on date of table2

The issue after my try it gets records then order it so i get some records not supposed to get

```
(SELECT  NULL AS dopu_id, NULL AS dopu_donation_id, NULL AS donation_date, NULL AS donation_doc_id, NULL AS dopu_remain_value, NULL AS total FROM dual WHERE (@total := 0)) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT  dopu_id, dopu_donation_id, donation_date, donation_doc_id, dopu_remain_value,
 @total := @total + dopu_remain_value AS total 
 FROM donation_purposes 
 LEFT JOIN donations ON donation_purposes.dopu_donation_id = donations.donation_id 
 WHERE @total < 8550 AND dopu_remain_value > 0 AND donation_purposes.dopu_purpose = 'manage' 
 AND donation_purposes.dopu_ref_id = 2 
 ORDER BY donation_date
 LIMIT 99999999999)
 
 UNION ALL

(SELECT  dopu_id, dopu_donation_id, donation_date, donation_doc_id, dopu_remain_value,
 @total := @total + dopu_remain_value AS total 
 FROM donation_purposes 
 LEFT JOIN donations ON donation_purposes.dopu_donation_id = donations.donation_id 
 WHERE @total < 8550 AND dopu_remain_value > 0 AND donation_purposes.dopu_purpose = 'manage' 
 AND donation_purposes.dopu_ref_id = 1
 ORDER BY donation_date
 LIMIT 99999999999)
```

This is my result :

[image]

But the correct result should be the same but without last record which has dopu_id = 3089 like that :

[image]

This point here that like as it gets record 3089 first because it has been inserted first and sum it to total value then just reorder the records .. that of course gives me unexpected result

Comment: Is this a MySQL query? If yes, what is the version?

Comment: Inline operations with user-defined variables needs in definite rows processing order. Which cannot be provided in multiple-table query. Join in subquery then process in outer query with needed ORDER BY.

Comment: @likiCrus 5.0.12

Comment: @eng.ahmed - 5.0.12 ?? All bets off...